# How to unlock a locked user account using Terminal

Tags: terminal, catalina, user-account, unlock

How can I unlock a locked user account( after user entered password x times ) using Terminal on Catalina. 
I check if the user is locked by doing `sudo pwpolicy -u username -authentication-allowed` which gives me `User <username> is not allowed to authenticate: Failed record policy "Authentication Lockout"`

What I tried:

`sudo pwpolicy -u username enableuser` - says enabling account but user is still locked

`sudo pwpolicy -u username -setpolicy "isDisabled=0"` - I know it's deprecated but I tried it anyway and it didn't work

`sudo pwpolicy -u username -setpolicy "minutesUntilFailedLoginReset=0"` - getting desperate here. didn't work

Any ideas?